# Validation in flex input text field

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

i have a program in flex wherein i check if a particular field is validated then the submit button is enabled. I am trying something like this:

```
public function init():void
    {
        submit.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE,enableSubmit);
    }

    public function enableSubmit(event:TextInput):void
    {
     //some code to enable the button
    }
```

I can call init in creation complete to add event listener to submit! is this the correct way to do it ? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can call the `init` in the `creationComplete`.
The only thing you need to change in your code is the parameter of the `enableSubmit` from `TextInput` to `Event` because the event is passed by parameter, like the code below:

```
public function enableSubmit(event:Event):void
{
//some code to enable the button    
}
```

Also the event listener need to be added to the TextInput, so I am assuming that **submit control** is the TextInput `submit.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE,enableSubmit);`